# (mysql) how to add wildcard on where condition when joining with another table?

Tags: mysql

i have one query that need some changes, and i don't get any clue to do this :

this is my query :

```
select * from user_data a
left join user_group b 
on (a.role like b.role)
```

actually role value in userdata is (varchar)*'staff'*

and role value in group is (varchar)*'staff;security;finance'*

so i don't get result what i expected ..

i imagine the query should be similar to this :

```
select * from user_data a
left join user_group b 
on (b.role like a.role+";%") // using wildcard
```

and i still don't know the right query using wildcard to this case

any one can help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

```
select * from user_data a
left join user_group b 
on (b.role like CONCAT(a.role,";%")) // using wildcard
```

Note - does `b.role` only have to match `a.role` at the beginning? what if it was `security;staff;finance`? You could do `CONCAT('%',a.role,'%')`.

You could do `CONCAT('%','a.role','%')` to handle matching `a.role` at any position, but **only if** you can be sure that you won't have nested roles.
For example: if `b.role` is `staff` and `a.role` is `finance;gardenstaff;security`, then this row will be returned from the query even though the role is `gardenstaff` and not staff.

As an alternative, you can use [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) instead of `LIKE`. This is basically a regular-expressions verson of `LIKE`.

In particular, the regex `[[:<:]]staff[[:>:]]` will match the *whole word* `staff`. The `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` stand for *word boundaries*, which stop you from matching the `staff` in `gardenstaff`.

So, your query could be:

```
select * from user_data a
left join user_group b 
on (b.role RLIKE CONCAT('[[:<:]]',a.role,'[[:>:]]'))
```

And this would work for `b.role` being anywhere in the semicolon-separated `a.role`.

Comment: exactly i will make three conditions for the query,
in front, in the middle or in the last ..

so i'll repeat the condition 3 times using OR and change the wildcard position ..
do you think it's better?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee : thanks, nice to learn something every day.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee : your first answer has solved my problem .. and now i know something new that can shorten my query ..
thanks for your explanation ..